# Sort data in phpmyadmin table according to timestamp

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a table in phpmyadmin which contain data from different deviceid and each have a timestamp value in one column. I want to see only data from the particular deviceid which is sorted by the latest timestamp

My table is like

```
S.no. DEVICEID Timestamp             value1 value2
23.     Abc1.   12/05/2018.12:12:23   23.      26     
24.    Abc2.    11/05/2018.10:09:13   25.      21
```

Comment: _SELECT TOP 1..._ in mysql? Really? Read question and tags carefully... @Tomm

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY Timestamp DESC LIMIT 1` @B001ᛦ people make mistakes, escpecially since I primarely work in sql... This can happen

Comment: *"I have a table in phpmyadmin"* ... <pedant>Technically you've got a table in MySQL which you're managing through PHPMyAdmin</pedant> (oki, technically, technically there *is* an HTML table in PHPMyAdmin which is representing the MySQL table - and since you didn't specify the type of table...)

Answer (score 0):

We could run a MySQL SELECT query something like this:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM my_table_is_like t
 WHERE t.deviceid = 'Abc2.'
 ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC
```

This would return rows for a "particular deviceid" with the row with the "latest timestamp" first.

(This assumes the timestamp column is DATETIME or TIMESTAMP datatype. If its  stored as a character type in a canonical format, then we can convert that to DATETIME using the `STR_TO_DATE` function, and order by the return from that expression.)

The question (?) isn't very clear as to the expected result.

Comment: MY timestamp is in varchar datatype and its format is dd/mm/yy hour/min/seconds. So converting it can cause problem to me??

Comment: `ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(t.timestamp,'%m/%d/%y %H/%i/%s') DESC` ... The STR_TO_DATE function will return NULL when a string can't be converted to a datetime using the specified format.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date   MySQL has `DATETIME` datatype which is custom designed for storing datetime values, prevents invalid or malformed datetime values from being inserted, ORDER BY and comparison works on the datetime column, without need to convert. Consider changing your table definition to use DATETIME instead of VARCHAR for datetime values.